# Start method exception, MainController ClassNotFound

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml

I have some problems. I added GUI and I can't run my app. I was trying set sources in other way but it not helped.

Start class:

```
public class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("gui/Main.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setMinHeight(600);
    stage.setMinWidth(800);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

I was trying:

```
("/gui/Main.fxml"); 
("Main.fxml"); 
("/Main.fxml"); 
("gui/Main") etc.
```

Main class:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException {

        String databaseUrl = "jdbc:sqlite:bazadanych.db";

        ConnectionSource connectionSource;
        connectionSource = new JdbcConnectionSource(databaseUrl);


        Dao<Klient, Integer> klientsDao =
                DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, Klient.class);
        Dao<Samochod,Integer> samochodsDao =
                DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, Samochod.class);
        Dao<Usterka,Integer> usterkasDao =
                DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, Usterka.class);

        launch(args);


        connectionSource.close();
    }
```

First line of FXML file:

```
<AnchorPane minHeight="600.0" minWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="gui/MainController">
```

Controller:

```
package gui;

public class MainController implements Initializable {


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }

}
```

Error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=55783:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Kowali\Desktop\Projekt0-2\Projekt\target\classes;C:\Users\Kowali\.m2\repository\com\j256\ormlite\ormlite-jdbc\5.1\ormlite-jdbc-5.1.jar;C:\Users\Kowali\.m2\repository\com\j256\ormlite\ormlite-core\5.1\ormlite-core-5.1.jar;C:\Users\Kowali\.m2\repository\org\xerial\sqlite-jdbc\3.25.2\sqlite-jdbc-3.25.2.jar" Main
2018-12-04 16:10:59,239 [DEBUG] DaoManager created dao for class class Klient with reflection
2018-12-04 16:10:59,241 [DEBUG] DaoManager created dao for class class Samochod with reflection
2018-12-04 16:10:59,245 [DEBUG] DaoManager created dao for class class Usterka with reflection
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Kowali/Desktop/Projekt0-2/Projekt/target/classes/Main.fxml:10
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:922)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at Main.start(Main.java:18)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MainController
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
    ... 22 more
Exception running application Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm working on Intelij so I moved FXML and Controller to resources but it not helped me too. I also read some responses on similar questions but they not helped me. I also trying to use FXML Loader, not Parent root. I dont understand too why in Intelij source to Controller is ok, but in teh end of error we can see its not found. I was trying to find the solution all day and nothin.

I was trying this too:

```
FXMLLoader loader = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
```

Answer (score 0):

The file it is loading is `C:/Users/Kowali/Desktop/Projekt0-2/Projekt/target/classes/Main.fxml`. It may be an old file. I suggest you delete that file, do Project -> Rebuild project in IntelliJ, and try running it again.

Also, you claim that your code is

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("gui/Main.fxml"));
```

but this is not consistent with the error message. So either you didn't save your .java file (but that's probably not the case since you're using IntelliJ, which saves files automatically), or this isn't the version of the code that matches the error message.